split next pairs into columns
I would like to convert nested data pairs into multiple columns.
Say below example, the IN and OUT in action columns is data pairs but it's nested.
import pandas as pd

data = [
 [1,'IN'],
 [2,'IN'],
 [3,'OUT'],
 [4,'OUT'],
 [5,'IN'],
 [6,'IN'],
 [7,'OUT'],
 [8,'OUT']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ts','action'])
print(df)

expected output is:
   ts_IN  ts_OUT
0   1      4
1   2      3
4   5      8
5   6      7

Any pandas method can handle this case?

Is the index significant? I ask because it goes 0, 1, 4, 5 instead of 0, 1, 2, 3.

You could use a custom python function, keeping track of the seen IN and yielding the last one every time you find an OUT:
out = {}
ins = []
for i, (s, t) in enumerate(zip(df['action'], df['ts'])):
    if s == 'IN':
        ins.append(i)
        out[i] = [t, None]
    else:
        i = ins.pop()
        out[i][1] = t

out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(out, orient='index',
                             columns=['ts_IN', 'ts_OUT'])

NB. this requires that a any point you don't have more OUT than IN.
Output:
   ts_IN  ts_OUT
0      1       4
1      2       3
4      5       8
5      6       7

Other example:
# input
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': range(10),
                   'action': ['IN', 'IN', 'OUT', 'IN', 'OUT', 'OUT', 
                              'IN', 'IN', 'OUT', 'OUT']})

# output
   ts_IN  ts_OUT
0      0       5
1      1       2
3      3       4
6      6       9
7      7       8


It looks like the pivot pairs 3 with 1 instead of 4. Same goes for the rest. It looks like your ts_OUT order is not naturally ordered.

@Mr.Polywhirl you're right, I misread the question. I provided another approach. That said, unless I misunderstood the "nested" in the question, I don't believe your approach would give the correct solution (see my second example).

You can create the initial frame and then filter the frame for IN and OUT values:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd

def pair_in_out(data):
    """Pairs 'IN' and 'OUT' timestamps into a single DataFrame."""
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ts', 'action'])
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'ts_IN': __filter_column(df, 'ts', 'action', 'IN'),
        'ts_OUT': __filter_column(df, 'ts', 'action', 'OUT'),
    })

def __filter_column(df, value_field, filter_field, filter_value):
    """Filters the DataFrame by the filter_field and extracts the value_field."""
    return df[df[filter_field] == filter_value].reset_index(drop=True)[value_field]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [
        [1, 'IN'], [2, 'IN'], [3, 'OUT'], [4, 'OUT'],
        [5, 'IN'], [6, 'IN'], [7, 'OUT'], [8, 'OUT']
    ]
    
    print(pair_in_out(data))

If you want a more dynamic version, you can pass in the columns/fields and filters:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd

def pair_columns_by_filter(input_data, column_names, value_column, filter_column, filter_values):
    df = pd.DataFrame(input_data, columns=column_names)
    return pd.DataFrame({
        f"{value_column}_{target}": __filter_column(df, value_column, filter_column, target)
        for target in filter_values
    })

def __filter_column(df, value_column, filter_column, filter_value):
    return df[df[filter_column] == filter_value].reset_index(drop=True)[
        value_column
    ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [
        [1, 'IN'], [2, 'IN'], [3, 'OUT'], [4, 'OUT'],
        [5, 'IN'], [6, 'IN'], [7, 'OUT'], [8, 'OUT']
    ]

    result = pair_columns_by_filter(
        input_data=data,
        column_names=['ts', 'action'],
        value_column='ts',
        filter_column='action',
        filter_values=['IN', 'OUT']
    )
    
    print(result)


In this case I would go for pure python solution, something like this:
import pandas as pd

data =[
 [1,'IN'],
 [2,'IN'],
 [3,'OUT'],
 [4,'OUT'],
 [5,'IN'],
 [6,'IN'],
 [7,'OUT'],
 [8,'OUT']
   ]
    
def InOutParser(data):
    res = {}
    res["IN"] = [None]*int(len(data)/2)
    res["OUT"] = [None]*int(len(data)/2)
    j = 0
    i = 0
    while len(data) > 0:
        while i < len(data):
            if data[i][-1] == "OUT":
                res["OUT"][j] = data[i][0]
                res["IN"][j] = data[i-1][0]
                data.pop(i)
                data.pop(i-1)
                i -=1
                j +=1
                break
            i+=1
    return pd.DataFrame(res)

print(InOutParser(data))


try this:
result = (
    df.set_index([df.groupby('action').cumcount(), 'action'])
    .unstack()
    .droplevel(axis=1, level=0)
    .add_prefix('ts_')
)
print(result)

>>>
action  ts_IN  ts_OUT
0           1       3
1           2       4
2           5       7
3           6       8


That was actually my first approach, but it's incorrect, OP wants a nested mapping (1→4) not a pairwise in order (1→3) ;)
